# Build List of Foo's with Specific Value at Compile-Time

Tags: scala

Given:

`case class Foo(x: BigDecimal)`

I'd like to, at compile-time, build a `List[Foo]` where each `Foo` must have a BigDecimal value of `5`.

So, I'd expect the following code to compile:

```
type Foo5Only = ???

val foos5: List[Foo5Only] = List(Foo(5), Foo(5))
```

But, I'd expect the following to fail to compile:

`val bad: List[Foo5Only] = List(Foo(42))`

I'm speculating that a `shapeless` Singleton type might be useful, but I don't actually understand it.

Note - I'm not interested, for this question, in an answer that results in using `Either` or `Option`.

Comment: Is `BigDecimal` a requirement? (Otherwise you might be able to use `Nat` and parameterize `Foo`)

Comment: @MichaelZajac - yes, `Nat` would work, thanks. For my own learning, would a Singleton type apply here - as an alternative to `Nat`?

Answer (score 1):

As well as using shapeless' `Nat` type you could also use singleton types. Unfortunately Scala's built-in List type has covariance which gets in the way of type safety, but using a simple hand-crafted list type seems to work:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

sealed trait Lst[T]
case class Nil[T]() extends Lst[T]
case class Cons[T](head : T, tail : Lst[T]) extends Lst[T]

def list[T](t : T) : Lst[T] = {
    Cons(t, Nil())
}

// OK
val foos5 = Cons(5.narrow, list(5.narrow))

// Compile-time type mismatch error.
val foos6 = Cons(42.narrow, list(5.narrow))
```

You might be able to elide the `narrow`s with some macro-magic, but that's beyond my ability.